# Parsing fixed width files with special characters inside the file?

Tags: python, django

I am parsing fixed width files. I am having an issue with a specific string. The string looks like this:

`(Pdb) record.description
'D\xc3\xa9cision financi\xc3\xa8re \xc3\xa0 long trem corrig\xc3\xa9'`

The fixed width file that I am parsing looks like so:

`LI    41000001009 Décision financière à long trem corrigé                                           14 00001100 0000000000 0000000000                 00080000 000000 00000 00000 00000 00081 N 05062006 00000273 00 00000000                                          00000001 00000000 00000000                 -------- 000005`

and the code that parses this and imports it into the database is here:

```
import struct, cStringIO, MySQLdb, glob, os, settings
from django.template.defaultfilters import slugify

cnv_text = lambda s: s.rstrip()

fieldspecs = [
    ('plu_number', 3, 15, cnv_text),
    ('description', 19, 80, cnv_text),
    ('price', 104, 8, cnv_text),
    ('member_price', 113, 8, cnv_text),
]

fieldspecs.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])

unpack_len = 0
unpack_fmt = ""
for fieldspec in fieldspecs:
    start = fieldspec[1] - 1
    end = start + fieldspec[2]
    if start > unpack_len:
        unpack_fmt += str(start - unpack_len) + "x"
    unpack_fmt += str(end - start) + "s"
    unpack_len = end
field_indices = range(len(fieldspecs))
unpacker = struct.Struct(unpack_fmt).unpack_from

class Record(object):
    pass

path = settings.PATH
files_to_delete = settings.GUTTER

for fname in glob.glob(path):
    with open(fname, 'r') as f:
        f = cStringIO.StringIO(f.read())
        for line in f:
            raw_fields = unpacker(line)
            record = Record()
            for x in field_indices:
                setattr(record, fieldspecs[x][0], fieldspecs[x][3](raw_fields[x]))

            db = MySQLdb.connect('localhost', settings.USER, settings.PASS, settings.DBNAME)
            cursor = db.cursor()
            fixed_member_price = int(record.member_price) / 100.0
            real_price = int(record.price) / 100.0
            try:
                cursor.execute(
                    "INSERT INTO catalog_product \
                     (name, slug, price, member_price, plu_number, description, old_price, is_active, is_featured, quantity, meta_description, image) \
                     VALUES \
                     ('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '00.00', false, false, 1, '', '/media/images/thumbnail-default.jpg')",
                     [record.description, slugify(record.description), str(real_price), str(fixed_member_price), record.plu_number, record.description]
                )
                db.commit()
            except:
                db.rollback()
            db.close()
for the_file in os.listdir(files_to_delete):
    file_path = os.path.join(files_to_delete, the_file)
    try:
        if os.path.isfile(file_path):
            os.unlink(file_path)
    except Exception, e:
        print e
```

This code works great for import thousands of records at a time with normal strings but as soon as an import comes in with special characters it doesn't import. I think it's because the description field  starts at column 19 and ends at 80, the special characters add characters past 80 and it errors because it can't map the remaining fields. Does anyone know of a way I can retain the utf-8 string format so it doesn't try to import `'D\xc3\xa9cision financi\xc3\xa8re \xc3\xa0 long trem corrig\xc3\xa9'`?

Comment: FWIW, according to me those aren't "special" characters at all. Definitively not ASCII. Mais spéciaux? Non!

Comment: @SylvainLeroux: Every character is special in its own way.

Comment: @SylvainLeroux uhm, what?

Answer (score 2):

That *is* the UTF-8 string.

```
>>> print 'D\xc3\xa9cision financi\xc3\xa8re \xc3\xa0 long trem corrig\xc3\xa9'.decode('utf-8')
Décision financière à long trem corrigé
```

Comment: Ah, yea, that's true, I found that in my researching. I guess I have more of a dilemma here then because \xc3\xa0 adds extra characters to my string, this is messing up fixed width columns in my fix width file.

Comment: is there anything I can do to the string to before saving it to the database? I thought maybe just 

`(Pdb) record.description.decode()
*** UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)`

would be sufficient but that does not work very well given the error above, I understand the error.